# sunspot return all results for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I have in my controller this:

```
def boards
   @user = User.find_by_slug(params[:id])
     @search = @user.boards.solr_search do |s|
       s.fulltext params[:search]
       s.keywords params[:search]
       s.order_by :created_at, :desc
       s.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 1
     end

   @boards = @search.results
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :layout => nil}# panel.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @boards }
  format.js
end
end
```

In my view:

```
<table id="body_object">
 <% for board in @boards %>
  <tr class="attributes">
   <td>
     <%= board.id %>
   </td>
   <td>
     <%= board.name %>
   </td>
   <td>
     <%= board.description  %>
   </td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>

   <div id="content_pagination">
    <%= paginate @boards, :remote => :true  %>
  </div>
```

`@user.boards` in controller are every boards that belongs to user.

But I get every boards like `Boards.all`.

I want get only every boards that belongs to user.

I have tried with `@user.boards` but I have that paginate an array like sth:

```
@boards = Kaminari.paginate_array(@user.boards).page(params[:page]).per(1)
```

How can I fix this problem for sunspot?

### Edited: Added Console Test

```
1.9.2-p290 :094 > Board.all.size #I get count boards for Board.all
 => 4 

1.9.2-p290 :095 > user = User.first #I get the first

1.9.2-p290 :096 > user.boards.size #I get count for boards belongs to user
 => 2 

1.9.2-p290 :098 > user.boards.solr_search.total # This is the problem :O The result must be 2
 => 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem was fixed

The fix: To Model searchable block you have add the parent for this board **:user_id**, string if you have mongodb database and integer if you have sql database:

```
#search
  searchable do
   text :name
   string :user_id
 end
```

In controller for this case I have add `s.with(:user_id, @user.id)` and replace `@user.boards` with the Model name like:

```
def boards
   @user = User.find_by_slug(params[:id])
     @search = Board.solr_search do |s|
       s.fulltext params[:search]
       s.keywords params[:search]
       s.order_by :created_at, :desc
       s.with(:user_id, @user.id)
       s.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 1
     end

   @boards = @search.results
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :layout => nil}# panel.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @boards }
  format.js
end
end
```

Now works fine :D. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with SOLR returning more than you expect -- the rest of the code is fine as far as I can see.

First verify that the `params[:search]` has the value you expect (check the `development.log`), and if so, you should run `rails console` and try the search manually.

Comment: Thank you! I have checked in the console and return the same result :(. I have edited the post to add the tests in the console :)

Comment: I have added the solution in a response :D. If you want accept you can do it. Thank you!