# search with sunspot in nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot

I have 2 model

The **user.rb** model

```
Class User
 include Mongoid::Document
 has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy, :autosave => true
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
 field :name
 attr_accessible :name
end
```

The **post.rb** model

```
Class Post
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Sunspot::Mongo
 belongs_to :user
 field :name
 attr_accessible :name

 searchable do
   text :name, :boost => 2.0
   time :created_at
 end
end
```

In my controller:

```
def posts
@user = User.find(params[:id]) 
@search = Post.solr_search do |s|
 s.fulltext params[:search]
 s.keywords params[:search]
 s.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 50
 end
  @posts = @search.results
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :layout => nil}# panel.html.erb
   end
end
```

With this sunspot search in all the Posts in database.

I want that sunspot only search in post that belongs to `@user = User.find(params[:id])`.

**How can I do it?**

### The problem was fixed

You can seee the fix in [sunspot return all results for a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689531/sunspot-return-all-results-for-a-model)

Comment: If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> **The problem was fixed**
>
> You can seee the fix in [sunspot return all results for a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689531/sunspot-return-all-results-for-a-model)

~ answer per [hyperrjas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778094/hyperrjas)